# SoundCloud control without using iframe

Tags: jquery, controls, soundcloud

Is it possible to control SC player without using the widget/iframe? I followed the jQuery set-up link http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player and have a basic page with three songs:

```
    <div id="cloud">
    <div id="iPlay" class="iPlay"></div><br>
    <a href="https://soundcloud.com/jay-hitt/greetings-from-the-wilderness" class="sc-player">Greetings From The Wilderness</a><br>
    <a href="https://soundcloud.com/jay-hitt/some-people-never-learn" class="sc-player">Some People Never Learn</a><br>
    <a href="https://soundcloud.com/jay-hitt/faith-of-a-desperate-man" class="sc-player">Faith Of A Desperate Man</a>
    </div>
```

I'm using this to change the "play" image to "pause" but cannot seem to add a function that actually starts playing the player:

```
    $("#iPlay").click(function () {
    $("#iPlay").toggleClass("iPause");
    });
```

Is it possible with this set-up or do I have to go thru the widget..

Answer (score 1):

All methods are in this page :

https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API/wiki#widget-methods

> When you’ll get the widget DOM object with the help of the
>   `soundcloud.getPlayer` method, you’ll have access to the following
>   public methods:
>
> ```
> api_play()
> ```
>
> Player starts playing either from 0 or from the last paused track
>   position. In the case the widget contains multiple tracks it will
>   start playing the first track.

but you can do it by calling soundcloud api , and use stream wit css3

```
function soundCloudApiUrl(soundUrl, soundcloudApiKey) {
        return 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + soundUrl+ '&') + 'format=json&consumer_key=' + soundcloudApiKey +'&callback=?';
};
```

and use getJson methods from jQuery :

```
$.getJSON(soundCloudApiUrl(linkUrl, soundcloudApiKey);
```

the last steps consists to retrieve the data and apply it from an `audio` tag or a javascript audio player plugin

Comment: So you are saying the answer is NO, I have to set it up with the iframe widget. Followed your link, and at the top of the page it reads: !!!Important: This is a deprecated API version,

Comment: Seems rather complicated. take a look at the page I have -http://www.jayhitt.bpsites.com/soundcloud.html. Simple text links to songs. As far as I can tell (understand) this would not be simple to achieve with what you are describing. And you appear to have a higher level of understanding about how it all functions than i've been able to do for the last 8 hours of reading the docs and searching... the ability to use a few simple js functions is all I was hoping to find.